# Why did my Minecraft sheep come back, on her own after I killed her?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I think it may be a side-effect of a corrupted Minecraft world, but I can't quite be sure.

So, I killed the sheep as a result of my game lagging and when I went outside of the school to the playground area, I saw it even though I had just recently killed her.

I have no idea whether this is a glitch, a feature, or a Side-effect of a corrupt Minecraft world. It also could have been my brother.

Comment: Next time you ask a question you can leave out information like who you were playing with and what you were doing before and after as well as any other information that isn't relevant to the question.

Comment: Were you playing a custom map? If a chunk is corrupted, it will not save properly, and the blocks will reset to what it used to be when you load the game again. I am not aware of a glitch where entities got duplicated due to lag. You might have simply had 2 "Ms. Fluffy"'s in your world.

Comment: It's not a feature; it's likely a side effect of your corrupted world, or your brother naming another sheep.

Comment: Could you give us some Video or Screen Shot?

Answer (score 1):

It was probably your brother. If it was laggy, then it might have reset. Did you still have Ms.Fluffy's drops? If so, it probably reset her, but not your inventory, but I think it was you brother.